# How do I sign kernel modules in Linux to successfully install NVIDIA drivers using dkms?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, secure-boot

I use Kubuntu 18.04 and I'm trying to install NVIDIA driver using the run file provided by NVIDIA itself instead of using package managers.
I first Installed the following packages:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

Once was inside the file, I added the following and saved the file:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

ran the following and reboot the OS:

`$ dracut -f`

if you're not familiar with it, it's like this command:

`update-initramfs -u`

after restart I installed these required packages:

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential make acpid dkms libglvnd-core-dev libglvnd0 libglvnd-dev dracut pkg-config linux-headers-$(uname -r)
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install libc6:i386
```

that took care of all necessary dependencies

Since Secure Boot is Enabled (and I intend to keep it that way) to be able to continue installation I have to sign the kernel module to be able to install the NVIDIA drivers. but I have no clue how to for example how to make the required .der file from the kernel module but I know how to add it to DB in UEFI/BIOS so that the error would go away.
if I try to install with dkms it gets stuck at 5% and if I don't install with dkms I get this error:

`The kernel module failed to load, because it was not signed by a key that is trusted by the kernel. Please try installing the driver again, and sign the kernel module when prompted to do so.`

so how do I sign the kernel modules and output a .der file to add to secure boot database?

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy if you have not done it before.

1. Install `xca`, since it's easier to work with and create a self-signed cert or chain.
2. Store the root chain or self-signed cert locally in your cert database and run the import script. Not sure where that is on Ubuntu.
3. Install the kernel source
4. Run `<path to kernel source>/scripts/sign-file sha256 <path to cert root PEM> <path to cert CRT file> <kernel module.ko>`. Not the PEM & CRT can be both the same file.
5. Copy it to `/lib/modules/<kernel mod dir>/misc`, and if necessary, compress it.
6. Run `depmod`
7. You should now be able to `modprobe` it.

I'm sure the cert has to have code signing properties set.

I *think* that is it.